# Cut function returns NA for intervals

Tags: r, cut

I am trying to use the cut function to create age intervals. Unfortunately, I receive NAs for values that match the lower end of the first break.

For example:

```
AGE <- sample(18:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
AGE_GROUPS <- cut(AGE, breaks = c(18, 27, 36, 45))
DF <- data.frame(AGE, AGE_GROUPS)
```

For all the values where AGE is 18 and above 45, I receive NA in the AGE_GROUPS variable. How can I make sure that the lowest bracket in AGE_GROUPS includes 18 and how can I make sure that the highest bracket includes all values >= 45?

Comment: As an addition to the answer posted below, I'd like to post a trick that I usually do to get more sensible cuts, in terms of the ranges. I tend to "play" with the `min` and `max` values of the variable, depending on whether I need `[` or `]`. As an example see this `AGE <- sample(18:50, 100, replace = TRUE);
unique(cut(AGE, breaks = c(min(AGE)-1, 19, 27, 36, 45, max(AGE))));
unique(cut(AGE, breaks = c(min(AGE), 19, 27, 36, 45, max(AGE)+1), right = F))`. Only thing you need to check is that you don't have duplicate breaks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Breaks isn't just the intermediate breaks, it is the endpoints too. You can  make sure you get everything with

```
breaks = c(-Inf, 18, 27, 36, 45, Inf)
```

A little more conservatively, you could use

```
breaks = c(0, 18, 27, 36, 45, 120)
```

which can be useful for catching outlier coding errors. You may also want `include.lowest = TRUE`. See `?cut` for examples.

Comment: That solves my problem from a technical/practical side. Thanks! Conceptually speaking, does this mean that a break of 18 means that values of 18 are not included in the 18-27 bracket? Would I have to make a 17-27 bracket to this end?

Comment: The default is `right = TRUE`, which means *"the intervals should be closed on the right (and open on the left)"* (again, see `?cut`), i.e., the 18 to 27 interval will be `(18, 27]` (the default label), including 27 but not 18. For clarity, I would recommend using non-integer breakpoints, so if you want the interval to include both 18 and 27, use 17.5 and 27.5 as the breaks. Then it's nice and clear that both 18 and 27 are in that interval, but 17 and 28 are not. If you wonder why this seems a bit confusing, remember that `cut` doesn't just work on integers, it works on any numeric data.

Comment: Great, very helpful! I appreciate it.